# Find intersection among multiple columns and find the intersected elements

Tags: r

[file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sUjrKaPgqJRixmGoWrKfNo1WYOA_qloj/view?usp=sharing) input file

```
a <- read.csv("Studies_studies.tsv",sep = "\t")

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658982/cross-comparison-of-columns-of-the-same-data-frame
bb <- tcrossprod(table(melt(as.matrix(a))[-1])) * !diag(37)

dd<- setNames(cbind.data.frame(t(combn(names(a), 2)),
                               combn(names(a), 2, function(x) length(intersect(a[, x[1]],a[, x[2]])))),
              c("col1", "col2", "count"))
```

So far my code.

I can get the count between each pairwise intersection happening between the columns but Im not able to get the elements that is common or intersected between two columns.

**For example**
This `C0026998 C1879321  1310` I do find that there are 1310 elements common between those to ID but I'm not able to find the name of the ID that are column.

So that way if I extrapolate my problem what i would like to see is the pairwise intersection among all the elements and i would like to store the output dataframe.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

input file dput

```
structure(list(C0026998 = c(32621177L, 32586363L, 32504186L, 
32391628L, 32333156L, 32171069L), C1879321 = c(27276561L, 29286103L, 
29988143L, 30076173L, 30024784L, 30892988L), C0023470 = c(27276561L, 
29988143L, 30076173L, 30024784L, 26837842L, 29286103L), C0280449 = c(30024784L, 
30076173L, 30892988L, 31688884L, 30651561L, 31516032L), C0522631 = c(26055299L, 
12801839L, 10516750L, 28825596L, 12652469L, 16203817L), C1292775 = c(28883080L, 
10400416L, 22581002L, 1503929L, 9499663L, NA), C0023472 = c(26837842L, 
29091516L, 29498925L, 20525995L, 27217448L, 20525993L), C1292773 = c(30135184L, 
24440648L, 26273061L, 21508125L, NA, NA), C4545381 = c(30093401L, 
29933073L, 29437791L, 31227358L, 30541745L, 28555084L), C4707228 = c(26492932L, 
21791467L, 28179273L, 24077845L, 30287390L, 22362038L), C2939461 = c(28588020L, 
29988143L, 30076173L, 30510081L, 30024784L, 30963592L), C1336735 = c(28645776L, 
28844816L, 31400961L, 30545576L, 29241450L, 28588020L), C2827362 = c(29119847L, 
29486661L, 29567772L, 31775485L, 30670826L, NA), C3839741 = c(28494506L, 
26492932L, 30923103L, 25715404L, 28556489L, 25006131L), C3839868 = c(28473620L, 
25512507L, 31015209L, 29933069L, 29321554L, 21791467L), C4520840 = c(28246192L, 
23935018L, 21750082L, 10741700L, 9407724L, NA), C4528668 = c(28645776L, 
28588020L, 30510081L, 30409776L, 30093401L, 28844816L), C2825139 = c(29241450L, 
30541745L, 31152020L, 24663049L, NA, NA), C1332153 = c(24440648L, 
26273061L, NA, NA, NA, NA), C4721505 = c(18623376L, 21618422L, 
21685468L, 25196856L, 16985182L, 18353632L), C2826177 = c(27276561L, 
29286103L, 25512507L, 29079128L, 28473620L, 26789727L), C4324477 = c(29286103L, 
22375971L, 30153096L, 30368038L, 25006131L, 30054307L), C2826176 = c(27276561L, 
29988143L, 27959731L, 29286103L, 25512507L, 28588019L), C2827356 = c(27716285L, 
29177434L, 30952642L, 30418178L, 27126994L, 29656442L), C3711382 = c(30510081L, 
26492932L, 29991558L, 27927766L, 28490572L, 29860938L), C4704767 = c(30555165L, 
30055822L, 25540937L, 30135184L, 30545923L, 30361063L), C0027013 = c(22375971L, 
28962635L, 22375970L, 29515114L, 30185431L, 23216616L), C0153886 = c(30510081L, 
28644114L, 28588020L, 30555165L, 30024784L, 29304833L), C0279094 = c(28644114L, 
28588020L, 30510081L, 30555165L, 30076173L, 30024784L), C0279623 = c(27276561L, 
30555165L, 28588020L, 30076173L, 30024784L, 30510081L), C1142169 = c(28588020L, 
30510081L, 25512507L, 25540937L, 30409776L, 30668890L), C1275661 = c(29660836L, 
30963592L, 22579233L, 21880637L, 26772158L, 27121471L), C1292776 = c(30055822L, 
30115541L, 10025899L, 31152020L, 26577691L, 23129738L), C1320638 = c(27959731L, 
18489989L, 25425683L, 28179273L, 30510079L, 30655375L), C1737261 = c(29988143L, 
28645776L, 29933073L, 30545923L, 30361063L, 28336527L), C2826178 = c(25512507L, 
29286103L, 28473620L, 25611491L, 21242187L, 19059939L), C4744720 = c(30555165L, 
28644114L, 29597002L, 30541745L, 30118897L, 29660836L), relapse = c(32786187L, 
32601798L, 32564196L, 32391628L, 32333156L, 32062741L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

output what i have

```
dput(head(dd))
structure(list(col1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C0023470", 
"C0023472", "C0026998", "C0027013", "C0153886", "C0279094", "C0279623", 
"C0280449", "C0522631", "C1142169", "C1275661", "C1292773", "C1292775", 
"C1292776", "C1320638", "C1332153", "C1336735", "C1737261", "C1879321", 
"C2825139", "C2826176", "C2826177", "C2826178", "C2827356", "C2827362", 
"C2939461", "C3711382", "C3839741", "C3839868", "C4324477", "C4520840", 
"C4528668", "C4545381", "C4704767", "C4707228", "C4721505", "C4744720"
), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(18L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
2L), .Label = c("C0023470", "C0023472", "C0027013", "C0153886", 
"C0279094", "C0279623", "C0280449", "C0522631", "C1142169", "C1275661", 
"C1292773", "C1292775", "C1292776", "C1320638", "C1332153", "C1336735", 
"C1737261", "C1879321", "C2825139", "C2826176", "C2826177", "C2826178", 
"C2827356", "C2827362", "C2939461", "C3711382", "C3839741", "C3839868", 
"C4324477", "C4520840", "C4528668", "C4545381", "C4704767", "C4707228", 
"C4721505", "C4744720", "relapse"), class = "factor"), count = structure(c(1310L, 
1310L, 164L, 9L, 6L, 23L), .Dim = 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

from the above output i do know that  `C0026998 C1879321  1310` between C0026998 and C1879321 there are 1310 elements are common. Now the next thing i would like to find out is what are the elements that are common between those two IDs same goes for rest of the column which are to be compared pairwise.

The output I'm expecting is this

```
structure(list(`intersect(a$C0026998, a$C1879321)` = c(32621177L, 
32586363L, 32504186L, 32391628L, 32333156L, 32171069L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")


structure(list(`intersect(a$C0026998, a$C0280449)` = c(32171069L, 
31841594L, 31770437L, 31753773L, 31688884L, 31516032L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So in each column contain one Mesh term where there PMIDS which i want to find if these studies are overlapping or not.So in the above example i have given intersection between first four columns so i can see the IDs which are common. So i want to do the same with all the columns and save the results.

Comment: It'll probably help if you give a reproducible example and use ``dput(head(data))`` or ``dput(data[100,])`` or something, since most people won't want to download a random file from google drive.

Comment: Since StackExchange is not a code writing service you should try to ask a generic question that people can actually can benefit from. Please provide a representative input with `dput` and make it clear how the output is expected to look. I personally will never download random stuff from any GoogleDrive just to understand the question. It is the OPs duty to make this clear at first sight.

Comment: sure i will do it dput normal i do that but i thought file would be helpful i will update my question thank you for the suggestion

Comment: updated the question with dput.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output that you want?

Comment: okay will add the output what im expecting

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SE is not a code-writing service. 
There is a tendency recently that users post their data and then expect code to solve it.
Since these questions are often highly custom the community does not benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidyverse answer.

```
library("tidyverse")

results <- df %>%
  {gtools::combinations(ncol(.), 2, colnames(.))} %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair="unique") %>%
  rename(col1=1, col2=2) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(intersection=list(intersect({{df}}[[col1]], {{df}}[[col2]]))) %>%
  unnest_wider(col=intersection, names_repair="unique") %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("..."), names_to="col", values_to="val") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(col1, col2), names_sep="_", values_from=val) %>%
  select(!col)
```

The first few results.

```
> results[1:5, 1:5]
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  C0023470_C00234~ C0023470_C00269~ C0023470_C00270~ C0023470_C01538~
             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>
1         26837842               NA               NA         30024784
2               NA               NA               NA               NA
3               NA               NA               NA               NA
4               NA               NA               NA               NA
5               NA               NA               NA               NA
# ... with 1 more variable: C0023470_C0279094 <int>
```

Comment: let me try and i tired i do end up with this .."New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
Error in rename(., col1 = 1, col2 = 2) : 
  unused arguments (col1 = 1, col2 = 2)"

Comment: I think the problem comes this part the renaming part of the column `df %>%
  {gtools::combinations(ncol(.), 2, colnames(.))} %>%
as_tibble(.name_repair="unique") %>%
  rename(col1=1, col2=2)`

Comment: i think the issue is with my R version perhaps i was getting error in my Cent OS where R version 3.6.0 and when I ran the same code in Ubuntu which run R 3.6.3 i get the result as you have shown ..i think it is a version issue.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution it works..accepted the answer

Comment: @ rpolicastro i did a session clean up your code works perfectly fine in both then environment i think there was some issue with the namespace..

Comment: There are some other libraries that have a 'rename' function, so from what you said there was probably a namespace conflict. Another way to fix that is to explicitly state which library a function comes from, so for that case `dplyr::rename(...)`.

Comment: yes somehow i was able to figure it out...and thanks for the answer and code greatly helpful